# Renaming button.jsx makes entire react web unable to compile

Tags: reactjs

i've been tasked with renaming a Button.jsx file for my react web app into 'v2_button.jsx' however when I do so it makes the entire web app unable to compile as there are many times where 'Button' is called but not 'v2_button'. My question is how do I make it so that I can update the name of the jsx file and update every instance where the original Button.jsx is called into 'v2_button'?

Button.jsx file:

```html
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.Button`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;

  background: ${(props) => {
    let bg;
    if (props.disabled) {
      bg = props.theme.colors.disabled.background;
    } else if (props.color === 'secondary') {
      bg = props.theme.colors.primary.main;
    } else if (props.color === 'danger') {
      bg = props.theme.colors.danger.main;
    } else {
      bg = props.theme.colors.white;
    }
    return bg;
  }};
  font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.font.font3.new};
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: ${(props) => props.theme.fontWeight.heavy_900};
  letter-spacing: 0.105em;
  color: ${(props) => {
    let fontColor;
    if (props.color === 'secondary') {
      fontColor = props.theme.colors.textPrimary.light;
    } else {
      fontColor = props.theme.colors.textPrimary.purple.dark;
    }
    return fontColor;
  }};
  padding: ${(props) => {
    let padding;
    if (props.size !== 's') {
      padding = '0 39px';
    }
    return padding;
  }};
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: ${(props) =>
    props.disabled
      ? `1px solid ${props.theme.colors.disabled.border}`
      : 'none'};
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: background ${(props) => props.theme.animations.short} linear;
  :hover {
    background: ${(props) => {
      let bg;
      if (props.disabled) {
        bg = props.theme.colors.disabled.background;
      } else if (props.color === 'secondary') {
        bg = props.theme.colors.primary.light;
      } else if (props.color === 'danger') {
        bg = props.theme.colors.danger.light;
      } else {
        bg = props.theme.colors.secondary.light;
      }
      return bg;
    }};
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

export default Button;
```

Example where Button is called:

```html
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Button from "../../Button";

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
export const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
export const NameContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;

  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: ${(props) => props.theme.fontWeight.med_500};
  font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fontSize.med_16};
`;

export const List = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

export const FieldLabel = styled.label`
  height: 36px;
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.white};
  font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.font.font1.demi};
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  text-align: center;

  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: ${(props) => props.theme.fontWeight.heavy_800};
  font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fontSize.large_28};
  line-height: 50px;
`;

export const Selected = styled.label`
  width: 158px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fontSize.med_20};
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.white};
  font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.font.font1};
  caret-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.textSecondary.main};
  :focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  :focus-within {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 1px
      ${(props) => props.theme.colors.textSecondary.main};
  }
  ::placeholder {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.textPrimary.light};
  }

  background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.primary.main};
  border: ${(props) => props.theme.borders.textSecondary};
  border-radius: 4px;
`;

export const AddFieldButton = styled(Button)`
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fontSize.med_20};
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.textSecondary.main};
  background: none;
  width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
`;
```

Compiling error I receive after changing Button.jsx to v2_button.jsx:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFqdc.jpg

Comment: Your example doesn't show that `Button` is called

Comment: Are you using any IDE? If yes, there should be an option to rename file.
If not, you can use `sed` bash command to replace every occurrence of the old filename

Comment: Hi Vadim, I'm currently using VS Code is that sutible?

Comment: Basically you want a shortcut to update all imports?

Comment: Hi @Ergis, yes I think that's the fix i'm looking for, if you can take a look at the imgur link for the compiling error I receive after updating the name of the file of Button.jsx it reveals my problem

Comment: I think React components must start with a capital letter.

Comment: How big is the project, if you're on VS Code, you can hit CTRL + SHIFT + F, and find every occurrence of button, button.jsx, Button, Button.jsx in your code and correct it, you may use the replace many features as well. But take care when making refactors, such as a git commit.

Comment: @Alphasigma1436 Any feedback from you? Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to renamed all the imports.
But a 'workaround' to renaming all the imports could be:

1. Keep the `Button.jsx`
2. Instead of exporting the default implementation, import the implementation from v2_button.jsx file and re-export it from the `Button.jsx` file.

Thus, every import of `Button.tsx` will actually refer to the implementation of `v2_button.tsx` file.

---

Example:

**Button_v1.tsx**

```
const Button_v1 = () => (
    <>Button v1</>
);

export default Button_v1;
```

**Button_v2.tsx**

```
const Button_v2 = () => (
    <>Button v2</>
);

export default Button_v2;
```

Since all other files reference **Button_v1** and you don't want OR can't update the imports, you could do this:
**Button_v1.tsx** (after)

```
import Button_v2 from "./Button_v2"; // <-- ADDED THIS

const Button_v1 = () => (
    <>Button v1</>
);

// export default Button_v1; // <-- COMMENTED THIS
export default Button_v2; // <-- ADDED THIS
```